# finding an acyclic but not contractible space

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm studying singular homology, and have come across the term acyclic.
I understood that a contractible space is acyclic, but can't find a counterexample showing the inverse is false.

Could anyone suggest me (hopefully the easiest) example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider the exterior of the [Alexander Horned Sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere). (see Hatcher-Algebraic Topology, p.169)

Comment: ah, that is a much better example :)

Answer (score 4):

A counterexample is the punctured [Poincare Homology Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere#Poincar.C3.A9_homology_sphere).

Comment: Maybe the **punctured** Poincare homology sphere

Comment: @Dario fixed, thanks :)